# Server is unwilling to perform - Can not create user object in active state

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have managed to `connect, query and add to AD`. When adding a `user object` with **exampleA**(look down) `attributes` set I have no problem, however when I add:

```
$this->newUserEntry["UserAccountControl"] = 512; //LDAP will disable the account by default, This will create it in an enabled state
```

I get the following warning from `ldap_add()` and `user object` is not created:

```
Server is unwilling to perform
```

**ExampleA:**

```
        $this->newUserEntry["objectclass"][0] = "top";
        $this->newUserEntry["objectclass"][1] = "person";
        $this->newUserEntry["objectclass"][2] = "organizationalPerson";
        $this->newUserEntry["objectclass"][3] = "user";

        //---------General Tab-----------------------------------------
        $this->newUserEntry['givenname'] = $this->givenName; //first name
        $this->newUserEntry['sn'] = $this->sn; // last name
        $this->newUserEntry["displayname"] = $this->sn.', '.$this->givenName; // display name - Format: Meow, Test
        $this->newUserEntry["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] = $this->location; //office
        $this->newUserEntry["mail"] = $this->userMail;
        $this->newUserEntry["mailNickname"] = $this->userMail; // user mail

        //Change this to mobile field
        $this->newUserEntry["telephoneNumber"] = '9897157910'; // user phone

        //----------Account Tab----------------------------------------
        $this->newUserEntry["userPrincipalName"] = $this->samaccountname.'@comp.com'; //User logon name
        $this->newUserEntry["sAMAccountname"] = $this->samaccountname; //pre windows 2007 logon name


        //----------profile Tab-----------------------------------------
        $this->newUserEntry["scriptPath"] = $this->scriptPath; //Log on script

        //----------Organization Tab------------------------------------
        $this->newUserEntry["title"] = $this->title;
        $this->newUserEntry["department"] = $this->department; // department
        $this->newUserEntry["company"] = "Open Doors Test"; // Company name
        $this->newUserEntry["manager"] = $this->managerDn; // name of the manager
```

**What I have tried:**

1-Setting `password attribute`:

I taught that this is happening because I do not have password `attribute` set, so I tried adding a `password` with `hashing` and without `hashing`:

*password example: As33557b*

```
$this->newUserEntry["userPassword"] = '{MD5}' . base64_encode(pack('H*',md5($this->password))); //md5HASH - hash the password
```

Again both attempts it failed and like before if I would remove account control user object was created with no issues.

2- Make sure the connection is over `SSL`:

I changed the way I was connecting via `LDAP`:

**Before:**

```
ldap_connect('ldap://'. $this->dnToConnect)
```

**After:**

`ldap_connect('ldap://'. $this->dnToConnect, 636)`

I also ran `nmap -p 636 mydomain.com` to make sure the `port is open` and I can make a connection.

3- Try setting `512` value as a `string` and as an `integer`.

Notes: 
I can make `accounts, disable and enable` them manually, so the problem should not be with the `user and password` that I am using to `bind`.

**Update1:**

I have narrowed down the problem to the password. I can create an `Enabled account` with `no password` and setting `userAccountControl to 544`, so I think the issue is with the way I am setting the password field.
*Bloob is about to pop, any help would be appreciate it.*

**Comment Section Requested Info:**
Password:

originally I was setting the password like:

```
//$this->newUserEntry["userPassword"] = '{MD5}' . base64_encode(pack('H*',md5($this->password))); //md5HASH - hash the password
```

Than Someone suggested to try to set it like:

```
$newPassword = $this->password;
$newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\"";
$newPass = mb_convert_encoding($newPassword, "UTF-16LE");
$this->newUserEntry["unicodePwd"] = $newPass;
```

Comment: Does the key UserAccountControl exist in AD (in the schema for users)?

Comment: @Nic3500 yes it is there, as an example one of the users has userAccountControl 0x200 = (NORMAL_ACCOUNT), there is also a sAMAccountType 805306368 = {NORMAL_USER_ACCOUNT}

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that all users attribute of userPassword says <not set>, however when I create an account is setting that field according to my hashed value

Comment: @BlooB - I don't know how it is done in PHP & which library you're using; in C#, I use `directoryEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200;`  - note the hexadecimal use 0x, and `directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "yourPasswordInPlainText" });` to set the password.

Comment: How are you setting the password? Can you change a password? Show Code.

Comment: @jwilleke I added the chunks of code you requested to the posts body at the end.

Comment: Can you try to connect securely with ldap**s**:// instead of ldap://? `ldap_connect('ldaps://'$this->dnToConnect, 636)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone, the reason I couldn't create an account in `active state` was due not not being able to set the attribute `unicodePwd` and this was due to not being able to connect over `LDAPS`.

I couldn't connect over `LDAPS` due to lack of the needed certificate and some configurations.

Resolution:

1-

a. Create following folders in your `C:` Directory (At the same level you see your `phps top folder`)

```
openldap -> sysconf
```

b. In **sysconf** folder:

b1. create a ldap.conf file and add the following lines:

```
   TLS_CACERT C:\openldap\sysconf\ssl\cacert.pem
   TLS_REQCERT     never
```

b2. create a folder in `sysconf` named `ssl`:

```
   you will put a `certificate` in there (look at part 2 for details)
```

2- go to the host that hosts your `Active directory`, ask your Admin to do perform the instructions in the link below, and `put the cert in ssl folder`, also remember to convert the cert using `openSSL`:

```
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2980.ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-certificate.aspx
```

3- You can use the script below to test:

```
<?php

  $ldaphost = "ldaps://hostNameOfDC.DCName.com";
  $ldapUsername  = "adminUser@DCName.com";
  $ldapPassword = "adminPASS";

  $ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost,636);
  if(!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)){
  print "Could not set LDAPv3\r\n";
  }
  else {
// now we need to bind to the ldap server
     $bth = ldap_bind($ds, $ldapUsername, $ldapPassword) or die("\r\nCould not connect to LDAP server\r\n");
  }

  if($bth){ echo"WEEEE you did it"; }

?>
```

4- How to set `unicodePwd` (password [credit to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300608/getting-will-not-perform-error-when-trying-to-enable-user-via-ldap?rq=1)):

```
        $newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\"";
        $newPass = mb_convert_encoding($newPassword, "UTF-16LE");
        $this->newUserEntry["unicodePwd"] = $newPass;
```